# How can I use introspection to get Python to tell me more about PIL ImagingCore objects?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, introspection

Something I'm doing in PIL is giving me back an object of a class I don't recognize. It may be a fairly thin wrapper around a C data structure or something. How can I get Python to tell me where to look for more information?

Here are some failed attempts to use introspection to learn more:

```
>>> import os, PIL
>>> obj = PIL.Image.open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/foo.png")).getdata()
>>> type(obj)
<type 'ImagingCore'>
>>> ImagingCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ImagingCore' is not defined
>>> PIL.ImagingCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ImagingCore'
>>> obj.__class__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __class__
>>> obj.__module__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __module__
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getsource(obj)
...
TypeError: <ImagingCore object at 0x105e64b50> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
>>> inspect.getsource(type(obj))
...TypeError: <module '__builtin__' (built-in)> is a built-in class
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL's core functionality is implemented in module `_imaging`, written, as you guessed, in the C language -- see `_imaging.c` (3281 lines...:-) in the top level source directory, Imaging-1.1.7.  That code doesn't pay any attention to introspection -- rather, it's 100% focused on performance.  I believe it doesn't even bother to expose anything but functions (it does implement several types, including ImagingCore, but doesn't even expose those types' names to Python -- only generates and uses them internally).

So Python won't tell you where to look for more info because the library, in turn, doensn't tell Python:-).  As the docs for `getdata` at http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm says:

> Note that the sequence object returned by this method is an internal
>   PIL data type, which only supports certain sequence operations,
>   including iteration and basic sequence access. To convert it to an
>   ordinary sequence (e.g. for printing), use `list(im.getdata())`

...and "that's all she wrote" -- nothing but that small subset of sequence operations gets exposed.